# running python scripts through bumblebee from pydev

Tags: ubuntu, pydev

I am trying out things with Bumblebee and Ironhide on Linux; both are ways to run code on the fast graphic cards in hybrid graphics systems.

The way that works is that if I run this in the terminal:
optirun glxgears
this will run the programme glxgears on the fast card,
but if i run 
glxgears
it will run on the slow graphics card as that is the standard behaviour.

Now how can I run my python code in Pydev with ´optirun´ as a prefix ?
I guess from the command-line it would have to be something like:
optirun /usr/bin/python2.6 mypythonscript.py

In the run configurations within PyDev I can not find a way to prepend ´optirun´ to the call to the interpreter
I tried making a shell script that calls optirun /usr/bin/python2.6 and passes all parameters, but PyDev is not that easily fooled and complains that the interpreter in question is already configured.
It would be great to be able to do this from PyDev, since then I don´t have to worry about the dependencies on other modules I made.

How can I achieve this  ?

kind regards,

Joost.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried it, but you can check if the following works:

Edit plugins\org.python.pydev_XXX\PySrc\interpreterInfo.py and in the line that does:

sys.stdout.write('EXECUTABLE:%s|\n' % executable)

Make it: sys.stdout.write('EXECUTABLE:optirun %s|\n' % executable)

Then, contfigure a new interpreter -- when using that interpreter, any python call should go through the optirun... If that fails, I think that the only other way would be editing PyDev itself to add an option to specify a 'prefix executable' (hardcoding should be easy: edit org.python.pydev.debug.ui.launching.PythonRunnerConfig.getCommandLine(boolean) to add optirun to the cmdArgs -- see: http://pydev.org/developers.html for details on getting the code/compiling it).

Comment: thanks still for this answer: for that project I ended up running everything on the fast graphic card, but I still want to try out your suggestions !